# Finding angle b/w two points

Tags: ios, swift, caanimation

Here is my problem, whenever I tap on any button it should come to center, I am using CGAffineTransform and CABasicAnimation, but I am not able to get the angle I should rotate with, each of them is a button in circle, any help will be appreciated[image]

code for rotation

```
func rotateBarrel(with duration:CGFloat,angle:Double) {
    let rotationAnimaton = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotationAnimaton.toValue = angle

    rotationAnimaton.duration = CFTimeInterval(duration)
    barrelContainingView.layer.add(rotationAnimaton, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    barrelContainingView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(angle))
}
```

code for angle calculation

```
func angleToPoint(comparisonPoint: CGPoint) -> Double {
        let originPoint = CGPoint(x:comparisonPoint.x-initialCenterPoint.x,y:comparisonPoint.y-initialCenterPoint.y)
        return Double(atan2f(Float(originPoint.y), Float(originPoint.x)))

    }
```

//initial center point is centre of 3rd button before rotation

Answer (score 0):

You want the function atan2. You pass in deltaX and deltaY from the center point to point 1 to get the first angle. Then repeat on the second point to get the second angle, then take the difference in angles. That's the angle of the arc.

I have a project on Github called [**TrochoidDemo**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/TrochoidDemo) that includes a one-finger tap gesture recognizer using this same math (for the gesture recognizer I calculate the change in angle from the starting point of your finger to the point you drag to.)

Here's the relevant code:

```
let center = CGPoint(x: view!.bounds.midX, y: view!.bounds.midY)
let currentTouchPoint = touch.location(in:  view)
let previousTouchPoint = touch.previousLocation(in:  view)

//Calculate the angle from the center of the view to the previous touch point.
let previousAngle = atan2f(Float(previousTouchPoint.y - center.y),
                           Float(previousTouchPoint.x - center.x))
//Calculate the angle from the center of the view to the current touch point.
let currentAngle = atan2f(Float(currentTouchPoint.y - center.y),
                          Float(currentTouchPoint.x - center.x))

//Adjust the rotation by the change in angle.
rotation -= CGFloat(currentAngle - previousAngle)
```

It'll need adaptation to work for you, but it should show you the basic idea.